# Which build.gradle files should we consider and why?

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio, android-annotations

This question regards the issue I've faced during integrating `android-annotations` framework with `gradle` in `android studio`. Here https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle
are hints how to integrate this with android project. Unfortunately I'm not advanced with `gradle` and google does not serve effective help with Gradle Sync Error:

```
Error:(28, 0) Could not find property 'plugin' on root project 'value'.
```

which indicates on line with 
`apply plugin 'com.android.application'`
that I've added during `annotations` integration.

ENV:

```
Android Studio (Beta) 0.8.9
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.4
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Monday, September 9, 2013 8:44:25 PM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on April 8 2014
Ivy: non official version
JVM: 1.7.0_65 (Oracle Corporation 24.65-b04)
OS: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic amd64
```

Appreciate any sollution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` (note the colon).